# How do I undo Windows settings that a local administrator applied?

Tags: windows-7, vpn

The user in question used to be a local administrator.  I need to do the following:

1. Remove any VPN connections that the user would have created so that only their user account could access them.
2. Remove any programs that the user installed for their user account only.

I need to do these without breaking their password or logging them off.  How?

Answer (score 1):

If you have admin rights as well, you can go into the registry, load their hive and browse their Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall area and run any uninstall strings you see. This won't work every time tho. The only real way to clear everything out would be to change their password, log in and uninstall from appwiz.cpl.